# Deciphering a coding assignment description

Tags: c++, list, pointers, vector

I have an assignment for class. I do not want any help with the code, just opinions on what you guys think he means by one line. I emailed my professor but he is slow to email back.

"Assume that nodes (class objects) q1, q2.....qk are loaded into a binary tree based on a value M in their private data. Now assume that M represents the number of edges that point to other nodes, where M < n/10 and is generated randomly, e.g. **that the original node is connected to and that a STL list of those nodes addresses is contained inside each node**....."

I'm confused about the bolded part. I know I have to make a list. That part is simple. I originally started making a vector of nodes, and inside each node, there is an stl list of ints that makes which other nodes it can go to.

EX:

```
vector<Node> nodes;
    list<int> edgesItCanGoTo; //part of node class
```

Using vector.at(number) as the address, as in each node element. I was wondering if you guys think he meant address as in pointer address rather than what I did.

I'm not asking for any coding advice, just opinions on my situation.

Comment: Each node in the binary tree has a std::list<Node*> that defines edge definitions from "the" node to "those" nodes. That being said, this better use pointers in that tree or thats a crap-ton of edge lists to maintain. Personally, I like your approach better for this assignment.